# Autofac and memory leak with BeginLifetimeScope / DbContext has been disposed / C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I am using NServiceBus Scheduler that's why I'm forced to use BeginLifetimeScope to avoid memory leak.

Method:

```
public void Start()
{
    using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var jobs = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IJob>>();

        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            _schedule.Every(job.GetTimeInterval(), () =>
            {
                job.Run();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And Autofac Configuration for context:

```
private static void RegisterContext(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register(c => new MyContext(GetConnectionString())).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

If `MyContext` has `InstancePerLifetimeScope` then whilst I'm trying to use it - I have an error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'`

So if I'll change it to `SingleInstance()` then of course everything works but context isn't disposed and I can have memory leak...

---

@EDIT

I have fixed the problem, here is solution:

```
public void Start()
{
    List<Type> jobTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(ExpiryDateTask) };

    foreach (var jobType in jobTypes)
    {
        _schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
        {
            using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var job = scope.Resolve<IJob>();
                job.Run();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I wondering how can I refactor this part:

1. `List<Type> jobTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(ExpiryDateTask) };` -
   that list should be filled somehow by all Types of Tasks that implement
   IJob interface.
2. `var job = scope.Resolve<IJob>();` I think this is wrong and should looks more like `var job = resolveJob(jobType)` - so basically based on the type.

Comment: I don't see any place where you are using this ```MyContext``` in your code.

Comment: It's inside the job.

Answer (score 2):

It happens most likely because the job is run asynchronously, that is `job.Run()` is called after execution exits the using statement. At the time `job.Run()` is called, the lifetime scope is already disposed including underlying database context.

Try moving the using statement inside of the scheduler callback. After all it makes most sense to execute each scheduled job in a separate lifetime context.

### More details:

I suppose `MyContext` is injected into a constructor of a class that implements `IJob`, right? With respect to your original code I think there are two contradicting goals:

1. you instantiate each job upfront to `GetTimeInterval` and schedule it
2. each job can be run multiple times and each execution should have it own DB context and dispose of it when it's done.

> It's not possible to get both at the same time. You need to separate
>   the scheduling part from the execution part.

One way to do it is to use Autofac's `Metadata`. It allows you to take contextual info about a component into account before actually instantiating it. I've written up a working [code sample](https://gist.github.com/pbalaga/cd5ad4ca4d78a8e294586c5049f3cf88) that shows how to do it.

It boils down to:

1. registering a job with metadata

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<JobImplementation>()
       .WithMetadata<JobMetadata>(conf =>
           conf.For(meta => meta.Interval, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
               .For(meta => meta.Type, typeof(JobImplementation))
               )
       .As<IJob>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
   ```
2. resolving the specific job instance in scheduler callback using this metadata

   ```
           using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
           {
               //Select this one specific job by its metadata.
               var specificJobInitializer = scope
                   .Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<Func<IJob>, JobMetadata>>>()
                   .Single(jobInitializer => jobInitializer.Metadata.Type == jobDefinition.Type);

               IJob job = specificJobInitializer.Value();
               job.Run();
           }
   ```

Comment: I realized the same thing a couple minutes ago :) And still not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Please, check my edit. Maybe you can advice me something?

Comment: @DiPix check out my answer now, and let me know if that helps. I've attached a code sample I tested it on. Interesting question. :)

Comment: Someone already gave me solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622158/autofac-list-of-types-that-implements-interface-c-sharp-asp-net/50623723#50623723 I think is easier than using Metadata. Especially that you've put interval into builder.

Answer (score 0):

I will extend on pbalaga answer.
To avoid problem with disposed `DbContext`, one option is to use some kind of factory for `DbContext` and create `DbContext` inside job.
Another option is to use different scheduler that offers delayed job resolution, we used Quartz.NET with MassTransit and Topshelf, and there was option to provide own Scheduler like this:

```
ScheduleJobServiceConfiguratorExtensions.SchedulerFactory = () => container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
```

and if I recall correctly, job was resolved at the moment when it was supposed to be fired:

```
serviceConfigurator.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
            {
                q.WithJob(JobBuilder.Create<EventsJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("Events processing", "Events")
                    .Build);
                q.AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create().StartAt(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(30))
                    .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatMinutelyForever(1)).Build());
            });
```

Comment: I prefer NServiceBus.