# Autofac list of types that implements interface / C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I had the problem with Autofac and memory leak in NServiceBus Scheduler. But fortunately I fixed that.

[Autofac and memory leak with BeginLifetimeScope / DbContext has been disposed / C# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611670/autofac-and-memory-leak-with-beginlifetimescope-dbcontext-has-been-disposed)

But now I'm trying to refactor this part slightly.

My code:

```
public void Start()
{
    List<Type> jobTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(ExpiryDateTask) };

    foreach (var jobType in jobTypes)
    {
        _schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
        {
            using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var job = scope.Resolve<IJob>();
                job.Run();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I refactor this part:

1. `List<Type> jobTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(ExpiryDateTask) };` -
   that list should be filled somehow by all Types of Tasks that implement
   IJob interface.
2. `var job = scope.Resolve<IJob>();` I think this is wrong and should looks more like `var job = resolveJob(jobType)` - so basically based on the type.

---

@EDIT

Point (1) solved by [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface

Comment: @DavidG close, I'm not sure why it returns also this interface IJob instead only implementations?

Comment: Well `IJob` is assignable to `IJob`, you could also add in a check for the type being an interface, something like `type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !type.IsInterface`

Comment: [Actually, the first comment says exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface#comment30356361_26750)

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, thanks!

Comment: In future, please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question, you can use Autofac [child container registrations](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope) to do what you want:

```
foreach (var jobType in jobTypes)
{
    _schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
    {
        using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType(jobType).As<IJob>();
        }))
        {
            var job = scope.Resolve<IJob>();
            job.Run();
        }
    });
}
```

That way, classes that implement `IJob` will also benefit from constructor dependency injection.